# Twilio returning 400 Bad request

Tags: java, curl, twilio-api

I am executing a curl command for Twilio SMS API from Java Code. Below is the CURL command and I and sending data in JSON

```
curl, -X, POST, https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[AccountSID]/Messages.json, -H, Content-type:application/json, -d, {"Body":"This is First Message","Form":"+120XXXXX216","To":"+91XXXXXX476"}, -u, [AccountSID]:[AuthToken]
```

But I am getting error response twilio

```
{
"code": 21602,
 "message": "Message body is required.",
 "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21602",
 "status": 400
}
```

Is there anything on my command?

Answer (score -1):

Have you read over the sample cURL code on the [Sending Messages - Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) page?

1. You seem to have inserted a number of arbitrary commas (`,`). Not sure why you've done this, but nowhere in Twilio's documentation (linked above) does it mention to use these. If this is related to your Java implementation of this command, you should provide additional context around that (i.e., how the invocation is being performed in your code).
2. Also in the example linked, the URL parameters are sent using the `--data-urlencode` switch, which does a bit more URL encoding than the `-d` switch does.
3. While not directly related to the error message you're currently receiving, you're also attempting to pass a parameter called `Form`, when it's evident you meant `From`.

Try this:

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[AccountSID]/Messages.json --data-urlencode "Body=This is First Message" --data-urlencode "From=+120XXXXX216" --data-urlencode "To=+91XXXXXX476" -u [AccountSID]:[AuthToken]
```